# Find the PID's of all threads of a process without ps or pidof

Tags: busybox, pid

So the system I'm working on (BusyBox) has a `ps` that takes no command line arguments and `pidof` returns nothing even though it exists within `/sbin` and points to `killall5`.

Another issue I had is that `top` takes no `-H`, but you can hit <kbd>h</kbd> (not <kbd>H</kbd>) in top to view the individual threads.

Any tips on how I can generate a list of all PID's under a given process name?

Comment: What system is this? Why are you tagging as Linux? It does not sound like one.

Comment: I guess technically it's BusyBox, but I think Linux still applies.

Comment: Ah, no, BusyBox is not Linux though it can work with the Linux kernel. It is most definitely not GNU/Linux in any case.

Answer (score 21):

In case you have limited find (no -printf option):

```
find /proc -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name exe -exec ls -lh {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks! Extension to display command line for each process too: `find /proc -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name exe -exec ls -lh {} \; -exec sh -c 'echo -n cmdline: ; cat "${0%exe}cmdline" | xargs -0 echo ; echo' {} \;` by also looking at `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` as well as `/proc/<pid>/exe` (note: not perfect, some quotes may be missing from command line args)

Answer (score 2):

Looking for bash:

```
find /proc -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name exe -lname '*/bash' \
    -printf %h\\n 2>/dev/null | 
sed s+^/proc/++
```

Comment: Hey, so I think this is getting really close to what I'm looking for, but the version of find I'm working with does not have `-lname` as a possible expression.